# Assignment of a value from a foreach loop

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I would like to parallelize a loop like

```
td        <- data.frame(cbind(c(rep(1,4),2,rep(1,5)),rep(1:10,2)))
names(td) <- c("val","id")

res <- rep(NA,NROW(td))
for(i in levels(interaction(td$id))){
res[td$id==i] <- mean(td$val[td$id!=i])
}
```

with the help of **foreach()** of the **library(doParallel)** in order to speed up computations. Unfortunately foreach doesn't seem to support direct assignments, at least

```
registerDoParallel(4)
res <- rep(NA,NROW(td))
foreach(i=levels(interaction(td$id))) %dopar%{
res[td$id==i] <- mean(td$val[td$id!=i])}
```

doesn't do what I want (give the same result as the normal loop above). Any ideas what I am doing wrong or how I could somehow "hack" the **.combine** option in foreach in order to do what I want? Please note that the order of the id variable is not always the same in the original data set. Any hint would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your performance gain will be better by orders of magnitude if you use data.table for this instead of parallelization of a loop:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(td)

DT[, means := mean(DT[-.I, val]), by = id]

identical(DT$means, res)
#[1] TRUE
```

If you want to use `foreach` you'll need to combine it with a `merge`:

```
library(foreach)
res2 <- foreach(i=levels(interaction(td$id)), .combine=rbind) %do% {
  data.frame(level = i, means = mean(td$val[td$id!=i]))}

res2 <- merge(res2, td, by.x = "level", by.y = "id", sort = FALSE)

#    level    means val
# 1      1 1.111111   1
# 2      1 1.111111   1
# 3      2 1.111111   1
# 4      2 1.111111   1
# 5      3 1.111111   1
# 6      3 1.111111   1
# 7      4 1.111111   1
# 8      4 1.111111   1
# 9      5 1.000000   2
# 10     5 1.000000   2
# 11     6 1.111111   1
# 12     6 1.111111   1
# 13     7 1.111111   1
# 14     7 1.111111   1
# 15     8 1.111111   1
# 16     8 1.111111   1
# 17     9 1.111111   1
# 18     9 1.111111   1
# 19    10 1.111111   1
# 20    10 1.111111   1
```

Comment: With some algebra, I think the inner `DT[]` can be avoided: `DT[,means2:=(n*valbar-sum(val))/(n-.N),by=id]` ? ...where `n <- nrow(DT); valbar <- mean(DT$val)`

Comment: @Frank I've demonstrated that approach in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17896332/1412059).

Comment: hi! there was a post by Steve which was also correct but it disappeared for some reason. So I check your answer as correct. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 9):

To perform these computations efficiently in parallel, you need to use chunking since the individual mean calculations don't take much time.  When using `foreach`, I often use functions from the `itertools` package for chunking.  In this case, I use the `isplitVector` function in order to generate one task per worker.  The results are vectors, so they are combined by simply adding them together, which is why the `r` vector must be initialized to a vector of zeros.

```
vadd <- function(a, ...) {
  for (v in list(...))
    a <- a + v
  a
}

res <- foreach(ids=isplitVector(unique(td$id), chunks=workers),
               .combine='vadd',
               .multicombine=TRUE,
               .inorder=FALSE) %dopar% {
  r <- rep(0, NROW(td))
  for (i in ids)
    r[td$id == i] <- mean(td$val[td$id != i])
  r
}
```

This is a classic example of putting the original sequential version in the `foreach` loop, but only operating on a subset of the data.  Since there is only one result to combine for each worker, there is very little post-processing, so it runs quite efficiently.

To see how this performed, I benchmarked it against the sequential version and against Rolands's data table version using the following data set:

```
set.seed(107)
n <- 1000000
m <- 10000
td <- data.frame(val=rnorm(n), id=sample(m, n, replace=TRUE))
```

I include this because the performance is very data dependent.  You could even get different performance results by using a different random seed.

Here are some benchmark results from my Linux box with a Xeon CPU X5650 and 12 GB of RAM:

- [Sequential for loop](http://pastebin.com/zE8HbiT4): 359 seconds
- [Sequential data table version](http://pastebin.com/FbX2zLST): 208 seconds
- [foreach/doParallel/PSOCK with 4 workers](http://pastebin.com/zQtwb9HH): 104 seconds

So for at least one data set, it is worthwhile to execute this computation in parallel.  It's not a perfect speedup, but it's not too bad.  In order to run any of these benchmarks on your own machine, or with a different data set, you can download them from pastebin via the links above.

**Update**

After working on these benchmarks, I was interested in using `data.table` with `foreach` to get an even faster version.  This is what I came up with (with advice from Matthew Dowle):

```
cmean <- function(v, mine) if (mine) mean(v) else 0
nuniq <- length(unique(td$id))
res <- foreach(grps=isplitIndices(nuniq, chunks=workers),
               .combine='vadd',
               .multicombine=TRUE,
               .inorder=FALSE,
               .packages='data.table') %dopar% {
  td[, means := cmean(td$val[-.I], .GRP %in% grps), by=id]
  td$means
}
```

`td` is now a `data.table` object. I used `isplitIndices` from the `itertools` package to generate vectors of group numbers associated with each task chunk.  The `cmean` function is a wrapper around `mean` that returns zero for  groups that shouldn't be computed in that task chunk.  It uses the same combine function as the non-data table version since the task results are the same.

With four workers and the same data set, this version ran in 56.4 seconds, which is a speedup of 3.7 compared to the sequential data table version, making it the clear winner at 6.4 times faster than the sequential for loop.  The benchmark can be downloaded from pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/wax1LyEg).

Comment: +1 But I don't think it's appropriate to include converting from `data.frame` to `data.table` in the timing as you've done in seems. When we use `data.table`, we start off with a `data.table` in the first place.

Comment: Also, `mean(DT[-.I, val])` can just be `mean(val[-.I])` which is significant by saving the overhead of many calls to `[.data.table`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle  I'm inclined to agree.  I have another version of the benchmarks that don't include that conversion, but for this particular case, it doesn't make much difference.  Using microbenchmark, the conversion only takes about 42 milliseconds.

Comment: Looked a little closer and I now realise that `mean(val[-.I])` won't be the same.  How about `mean(DT$val[-.I])` though. Same idea: avoids overhead of `[.data.table`. Or even `mean(DT[["val"]][-.I])`.

Comment: Yes I'm seeing about 8 times faster with `mean(DT$val[-.I])` rather than `mean(DT[-.I,val])`. Your full size `n` and `m` choke my netbook though, so very interested in what you see.

Comment: @MatthewDowle  I've updated my answer based on your advice.  Using `mean(td$val[-.I])` did indeed improve the performance of the `data.table` benchmarks.  I also updated all of the benchmark scripts on pastebin.

Comment: Thanks and good, but I was expecting more given my testing. Can you clarify the version of `data.table` and R you're using in the answer please?  A `setkey(DT,id)` first should improve it further by reducing cache misses (see FAQ 3.3). And turning on `verbose=TRUE` might reveal further clues.

Comment: thank you very much for all your replies (all of you: Steve, Matthew, Roland)! You are amazing! The data.table solution works well. I don't understand how I could oversee this great package until now. With Steves solution I got the following error: "Error in obj$nextElem() : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'". Dou you have any ideas what could be the problem here? I of course tried it with Steves example data set.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I am using R 2.15.1 and data.table 1.8.10.

Comment: @SteveWeston: With your solution I got the following error: "Error in obj$nextElem() : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'". Do you have any ideas what could be the problem here? By the comments I suppose your answer is the one which I should mark as correct but somehow I can't get your  code working on my R installation.

Comment: @chameau13 Are you using one of the benchmark scripts that I uploaded to pastebin?  And are you sure that you have itertools installed?

Comment: @SteveWeston: itertools is of course installed but i used the code in the post above. i will try it with your code in the pastebin. sorry!

Comment: @chameau13 The code in the post are excerpts from the code in pastebin, which is what I actually tested.  If one of those scripts fails, it might help to see output from sessionInfo(), which might be best for you to post on something like pastebin.

Comment: @chameau13 The best solution is referred to in the comments of Rolands's answer.  By improving the algorithm, in combination with data.table, you can get incredible performance.  I've been trying to use that algorithm in conjunction with parallel computing, but it's hard to get any improvement, even with very large problems.