# Grouping and applying function to .SD but one rolling entry

Tags: r, data.table

I am wondering if there is an elegant data.table (v1.9.4) way to do the following:
group a DT by two variables and then compute some function on the grouped tables (.SDs) for all entries in .SD but one and that one should be rolling through .SD and putting the result back in DT. The result is thus (potentially) unique for each entry in the .SDs (and hence DT). You can think of it as computing some value for a peer group of an entry in DT and that peer group is determined by the two grouping variables (same properties as the entry in DT) but the entry itself.

I accomplished this with loops around a simple := in data.table's j, but was wondering if there is a pure data.table solution. I could imagine something like `.SD[i != id , := , by=1:nrow(.SD)]` inside `DT[]` could do the trick but:

> Using `:=` in the `j` of `.SD` is reserved for future use as a (tortuously) flexible way to update `DT` by reference by group

The solution I have is (compute `sum()` for group determined by `b` and `c` except rolling ID):

```
DT <- data.table(ID = c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),
                 b = c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2),
                 c = c("x", "x", "y", "z", "y", "x"),
                 Var1 = 1:6)

for (id2 in unique(DT$ID)) {
  for (b2 in unique(DT$b)) {
    c2 <- DT[ID==id2 & b==b2, c] 
       DT[ID == id2 & b == b2,
          Var1_sum := sum(DT[ID! = id2 & b == b2 & c == c2, Var1], na.rm=TRUE)]
  }
}

DT
   ID b c Var1 Var1_sum
1:  a 1 x    1        0
2:  a 2 x    2        6
3:  b 1 y    3        5
4:  b 2 z    4        0
5:  c 1 y    5        3
6:  c 2 x    6        2
```

Do we need that future feature `:=` in `.SD`'s `j` for this?

Comment: Roland's answer in [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893613/r-data-table-on-subset-excluding-by-value/17896332#17896332) is very nice! Adapted it to my situation (keept the mean as function, added NA handling):`dt[ , c("temp.mean", "NpeersPlus1") := list(mean(Var1, na.rm=TRUE), (.N - sum(is.na(Var1)) ) ) , by=c("b", "c") ] dt[ , excl.mean := (temp.mean * NpeersP1 - Var1) / (NpeersPlus1 - 1),    by=1:nrow(dt)]

Comment: Good you find the answer, you can then post it as an answer to not leave the question as unanswered.

Comment: Still looking for a general solution: the approach in my comment (that is Roland's solution) works for functions where the intermediate result (result for the whole group including the one to be excluded)) can be corrected later on for the entry to be excluded (here: mean, also: sum and the like). That doesn't seem to work for every function, e. g. a hash function for all entries in the group but the rolling one.

Comment: @Helix123: please post and accept your own answer, that's the proper SO etiquette when you solve your own question. It also increases the chance that someone else might generalize it and post a better answer. Code in comments is exasperatingly unreadable.